# Python - How to Extract Noun Phrase after Parsing in NLTK

Tags: python, text

I want to extract noun phrase from a parsed text using NLTK, but I don't know how to do it. I'm still searching it, but no luck yet. So I have to ask here.

The parsed texts are on the list and they're like this:

```
(S the/DT (NP phone/NN) has/VBZ a/DT (NP good/JJ screen/NN) ./.)
(S (NP ipod/NN) is/VBZ the/DT best/JJS (NP mp3/NN player/NN) ./.)
(S
  does/VBZ
  the/DT
  (NP player/NN play/NN dvd/NN)
  with/IN
  audio/JJ
  and/CC
  (NP video/NN)
  ?/.)
```

Previously, I used TextBlob to extract noun phrase, but for some reason, on the first sentence, the "phone" doesn't extracted, only the "good screen." Which is why I'm going back using NLTK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```
import re
s = """(S the/DT (NP phone/NN) has/VBZ a/DT (NP good/JJ screen/NN) ./.)
(S (NP ipod/NN) is/VBZ the/DT best/JJS (NP mp3/NN player/NN) ./.)
(S
  does/VBZ
  the/DT
  (NP player/NN play/NN dvd/NN)
  with/IN
  audio/JJ
  and/CC
  (NP video/NN)
  ?/.)"""

print(re.findall("(\w+)/NN", s))
```

`re.findall()` will search the whole string to find matches. The above tries to find and return what's in the parenthesis `(\w+)` which means a work, followed by `/NN`

Comment: How do you find all when they're in a list? I forget to mention that. I tried using that on list, but no luck.

Comment: What exactly do you mean and I didn't get you?